# Rails engine missing host error. Where do set this config?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-engines

Say I have a Rails Engine called `seasons`. Say in the main app I'm trying to link to a url inside the `seasons` engine. I'm trying to do this:

`seasons.winter_url`

but that throws:

`Missing host to link to! Please provide the :host parameter, set default_url_options[:host], or set :only_path to true`

Since I guess the engine doesn't have a host configured. I can solve it by doing this:

`seasons.winter_url(host: <something>)`

but that's ugly. What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

In the main app. Say your engine is called `foo`.

Create a new initializer. i.e. in `config/initializers/foo_engine.rb`:

```
Foo::Engine.configure do |config|
  config.routes.default_url_options[:host] = ENV['API_HOST']
end
```

`ENV['API_HOST']` is an environment variable.

Anywhere in your app. You should be able to call the `url` or `path` directly using: `winter_url` or `winter_path` (no need for `seasons.winter_url`).